# Openfire kicks me when I send <composing/> or <paused/> with a custom message type

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am using openfire as chat server in my service. I need to notify user when interlocutor starts or stops typing message in chat.

I add custom message type notification_chat and send message with  or  extras without body:

When user starts typing:

```
<message id="SD4Vy-8" to="682@server.com" type="notification_chat"><composing xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/></message>
```

When user stops typing:

```
<message id="SD4Vy-9" to="682@server.com" type="notification_chat"><paused xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/></message>
```

But after send this packet openfire closes connection! In spite of this message delivered to recipient and I can process it by type and extras.

Why openfire kicks me is this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you get kicked because you violate the XMPP specs. Adding new types to message is not allowed. You can only use the types defined in the RFC (normal, chat, groupchat, headline, error).
When you need custom information then add your own tags in your own namespace to message.

example:

```
<message>
   <x xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/extension1">
     <messagetype>notification_chat</messagetype>
   </x>
</message>
```

Comment: I can not use type chat for typing notify, old clients accept all messages with chat type and display it to users. I need new message type. May be possible configure server for new type?

Comment: as I said above only types of the following are allowed:
normal, chat, groupchat, headline, error. Custom types are not allowed an are a protocol violation and cause a disconnect on your server.